# How to define function in React Component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing my first steps in reactjs. This code should write "ON", but I get error:

> App.js: Unexpected token, expected (

**Code:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class Light extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {light:"On"};
    };

    function formatLightState() {
        return <h1>{this.state.light}</h1> ;
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {this.formatLightState()}
        </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderLight(){
      return <Light />
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderLight()}
        </div>
    );
  }  
}

export default App;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is `function` keyword. To define a function inside react component you don't need to use that.

Write it like this:

```
formatLightState() {
    return <h1>{this.state.light}</h1> ;
}
```

`Jsfiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/ynx2evyj/

Comment: thanks!, it worked. i can't belive i wasted so much time for this :(

Answer (score 0):

You way of writing the `formatLightState` function is incorrect. Also you will need to bind the function to access the state. In order to bind you can make use of `arrow` functions or `bind it in the constructor`

```js
class Light extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {light:"On"};
    };

    formatLightState = () => {
        return <h1>{this.state.light}</h1> ;
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            {this.formatLightState()}
        </div>
        );
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderLight(){
      return <Light />
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.renderLight()}
        </div>
    );
  }  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```